# Dictionary.com "amount of words"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

[Dictionary.com defines *wordage*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wordage) as "*quantity or amount of words*". Shouldn't it be "quantity or number of words"?

Comment: It's likely that *amount* is used because *wordage* takes a more *mass noun* approach.

Answer (score 0):

From Collins:
noun
words considered collectively, esp a quantity of words

and two examples
“He stammered indistinctly, searching for the correct wordage” (Tom Robbins).
Is the author's payment based on total wordage?
Hope this helps